# ::selection is skipping some lines

Tags: css, safari, selection

I have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akrm7uaL/) and if you try to select the text just part of it is in the correct color, the rest is custom blue.

```
::selection {background-color: #FF6347; color: #fff;}
::-moz-selection{background-color: #FF6347; color: #fff;}
```

Any way to fix it?

Tested on Safari 9.1.

---

**Chrome:**

[image: Chrome]

**Safari:**

[image: Safari]

Comment: i am little bit confuse

do you want this selection on specific element ?

Comment: or your code is skipping some element ?

Comment: Looks like this might be a Safari-specific bug. I've added the Safari tag.

Comment: I've added the images of the problem. Seems that safari doesn't apply those styles to pure text nodes. If you wrap those nodes with tome element (like `span`, `p`, ...), [it works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/akrm7uaL/7/).

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, the ::selection element has some problems with supporting chrome and safari.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection

To make it a little bit better viewing in chrome/safari you have to wrap your code between a span or a paragraph like so..

https://jsfiddle.net/akrm7uaL/8/

As you see, the text is wrapped in a div or span so all text is red when selected. unfortunately the browser will not support the spaces between the text, when you place a new div in your code. To solve this you have to place all your text in a span instead of a div and place it between one div like this..

```
<div><span class="circular"></span></div> <!-- instead of --> <div><div class="circular"></div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/akrm7uaL/11/

As I look at your code, I suppose you use the id's for javascript or php or something so it will not completely your case if you HAVE TO add the id's to your code..

Comment: @Vucko Nothing, my bad. I have deleted the return in my answer.